# Mac keeps randomly restarting after logic board replacement

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, hardware, kernel-panic, restart

I got my logic board replaced due to water damage a few days ago and ever since i've got it back, a few times a day my laptop has a kernel panic and restarts. This appears to happen when i leave it on sleep for prolonged periods of time. A few other symptoms have come up. Some service called 'YaraScanService' is eating almost all my RAM and all of my Safari passwords have disappeared. I've tried looking for people with similar issues but all the answers I have found haven't helped.

On my last restart I received the following message from the error handler:

```
Fri Sep 14 08:43:52 2018

*** Panic Report ***
Machine-check capabilities: 0x0000000001000c07
 family: 6 model: 61 stepping: 4 microcode: 43
 signature: 0x306d4
 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5650U CPU @ 2.20GHz
 7 error-reporting banks
Processor 0: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC0_STATUS(0x401): 0xb2000000000a0005
Processor 1: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC0_STATUS(0x401): 0xb2000000000a0005
mp_kdp_enter(): 13, 1, 4 TIMED-OUT WAITING FOR NMI-ACK, PROCEEDING
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff8019f8811a): "Machine Check at 0x00007fff437087db, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x0000000108fe5000, CR3: 0x000000023ee5004c, CR4: 0x00000000003627e0\n" "RAX: 0x001dffff9d97a6c1, RBX: 0x00007fd9be08ed00, RCX: 0x00007fff9d97a6c0, RDX: 0x00007fff9d9868a0\n" "RSP: 0x0000700004aa6a90, RBP: 0x0000700004aa6aa0, RSI: 0x00007fd9be536790, RDI: 0x00007fd9be08ed00\n" "R8:  0x00007fd9be536790, R9:  0x00007fd9be55a670, R10: 0xfa87c12a12bb2448, R11: 0xffffffffffffffff\n" "R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0x00007fd9be536790, R15: 0x00007fd9be55a670\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000000202, RIP: 0x00007fff437087db, CS:  0x000000000000002b, SS:  0x0000000000000023\n" "Error code: 0x0000000000000000\n"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-4570.71.2/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:168
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81235c3c00 : 0xffffff8019e6c1c6 
0xffffff81235c3c50 : 0xffffff8019f95274 
0xffffff81235c3c90 : 0xffffff8019f87544 
0xffffff81235c3d00 : 0xffffff8019e1e1e0 
0xffffff81235c3d20 : 0xffffff8019e6bc3c 
0xffffff81235c3e50 : 0xffffff8019e6b9fc 
0xffffff81235c3eb0 : 0xffffff8019f8811a 
0xffffff81235c3fa0 : 0xffffff8019e1ea5f 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: airportd

Mac OS version:
17G65

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Jun 21 22:53:14 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1AE5ACFD-3B6F-3D74-AD52-31F1430DBC6F
Kernel slide:     0x0000000019c00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8019e00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8019d00000
System model name: MacBookAir7,2 (Mac-937CB26E2E02BB01)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 5435310665194
last loaded kext at 4539825968446: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc 5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9d2f4000, size 28672)
last unloaded kext at 4695294974418: com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice   1.2 (addr 0xffffff7f9d2ed000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    2
com.malwarebytes.mbam.rtprotection  3.1.1
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.2.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.37
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   281.52
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.20.13
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.20.13
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.7f10
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.1
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphics  10.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   6.01.2
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    211
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphicsFramebuffer   10.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.12.6
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 439.70.3
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.50.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 133
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.51.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.50.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1241.31.1a9
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 281.52
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.20.13
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 680.2
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   680.15
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.20.13
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.20.13
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    378.26
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   211.15
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   519.20
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    519.20
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.7f10
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 133
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.7f10
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  1404.4
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    1404.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   205
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    53
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.40.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.7.8
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  53
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.60.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.70.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.70.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    680.15
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1

EOF
Model: MacBookAir7,2, BootROM MBA71.0178.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.2 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.27f2
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 6000, Intel HD Graphics 6000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, -
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, -
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.37.31.1a9)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.7f10, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0512G, 500.28 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 27.2
```

Comment: This could be memory, it could be with WiFi adapter, or something to do with the logic board.  Since you had it serviced, the first thing is to contact the repair center and have them address it.

Comment: Obviously you should promptly take the thing back to the repair shop and make them fix it right.  A hardware failure that's random could be any dammed thing at all.  Maybe the _new_ board's busted!  Also, depending on the type and extent of the "water damage" (a cup of coffee, or a trip to the lake?), other parts such as the power supply might need replacement too.  But, that should be the shop's decision.  The monkey's on their back to make it right for you.